# can't send push notification from a device-parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm trying to add the feature of push notifications in my app and i did everything correctly according to many guides but the push is never being sent (i don't see it in the push list in parse). On the contrary, when i send a push from parse to a specific channel( which is exactly what i want to do from the device), i do get a message on devices which subscribed to that channel.

```
doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
            push.setQuery(query);
            push.setChannel(listId);
            push.setMessage("Hey pal"+", it looks like "+cur_user.getUsername()+" added you to a new list."+" Log in to check it.");
            push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {

                    if(e == null){
                        Log.d("DONE BUTTON","im here");
                        onBackPressed();
                    }else{
                        Log.d("PUSH ERROR",e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });

    //update the list on the screen
    updateData();
}
```

I literally have no idea why it doesn't work.

- listId which sent to setChannel is a valid channel (I checked that) and it is included in the channels column in several installations in parse among other channels (i mean, i have installations with more than one channel and i want to send this message onlt to listId channel).